# IIS Worker Process stopped working and was closed

Tags: .net, crash, w3wp

I'm running iis 8 on windows server 2012.
I have two web applications one is a simple asp.net web app and the other is a .net web api app running on owin.

When ever i refresh any resource twice once immediately after the other there is a delay in the response and i have 3 entries in the event viewer log, an error + two "Windows error reporting"entries.

I took a test javascript file that have only "no data" text in it and tried requesting it directly in the browser (no  html just typing the js url in the browser) and I get the same results.
so there is no code involved and no applicative error in the resource (the js file) .
looked at the iis log found only the request to the js + favicon.co file both with result 200.

I'm at a lost ... I would appreciate any ideas

[I attaching the errors from the event viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUSvv.jpg) plus [event viewer Windows error reporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHpqA.jpg) and  the Report.wer.

thanks

**Report.wer :**

> "Version=1 EventType=APPCRASH EventTime=131858072059648150
>   ReportType=2 Consent=1
>   ReportIdentifier=078054be-e02b-11e8-9404-000d3af802a7
>   IntegratorReportIdentifier=078054bd-e02b-11e8-9404-000d3af802a7
>   NsAppName=w3wp.exe Response.type=4 Sig0.Name=Application Name
>   Sig0.Value=w3wp.exe Sig1.Name=Application Version
>   Sig1.Value=8.0.9200.16384 Sig2.Name=Application Timestamp
>   Sig2.Value=50108835 Sig3.Name=Fault Module Name
>   Sig3.Value=msvcrt.dll Sig4.Name=Fault Module Version
>   Sig[4].Value=7.0.9200.16384 Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
>   Sig[5].Value=5010ac20 Sig[6].Name=Exception Code Sig[6].Value=c0000005
>   Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset Sig[7].Value=000000000000128d
>   DynamicSig1.Name=OS Version DynamicSig1.Value=6.2.9200.2.0.0.400.8
>   DynamicSig2.Name=Locale ID DynamicSig2.Value=1033
>   DynamicSig22.Name=Additional Information 1 DynamicSig22.Value=7d7c
>   DynamicSig23.Name=Additional Information 2
>   DynamicSig[23].Value=7d7ce255a4f0efbe7c5576812b8e1ec7
>   DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3 DynamicSig[24].Value=9c9c
>   DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
>   DynamicSig[25].Value=9c9c6d565c320c0d4ed9397cda75a332
>   UI[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHpqA.jpg)=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe UI[5]=Check online for a
>   solution (recommended) UI[6]=Check for a solution later (recommended)
>   UI[7]=Close UI[8]=IIS Worker Process stopped working and was closed
>   UI[9]=A problem caused the application to stop working correctly.
>   Windows will notify you if a solution is available. UI[10]=&Close
>   LoadedModule[0]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   LoadedModule[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUSvv.jpg)=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>   LoadedModule[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHpqA.jpg)=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
>   LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
>   LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
>   LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
>   LoadedModule[7]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\iisutil.dll
>   LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
>   LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
>   LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
>   LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\pcwum.DLL
>   LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
>   LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
>   LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
>   LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
>   LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\user32.dll
>   LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
>   LoadedModule[18]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wphost.dll
>   LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
>   LoadedModule[20]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\nativerd.dll
>   LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
>   LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ktmw32.dll
>   LoadedModule[23]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\IISRES.DLL
>   LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
>   LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
>   LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
>   LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
>   LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll
>   LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
>   LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
>   LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
>   LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
>   LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscoree.dll
>   LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
>   LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
>   LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
>   LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\iiscore.dll
>   LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\faultrep.dll
>   LoadedModule[40]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\W3TP.dll
>   LoadedModule[41]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3dt.dll
>   LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HTTPAPI.dll
>   LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\slc.dll
>   LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
>   LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
>   LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
>   LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
>   LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
>   LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
>   LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
>   LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
>   LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
>   LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll
>   LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll
>   LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll
>   LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll
>   LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll
>   LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll
>   LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll
>   LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll
>   LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\redirect.dll
>   LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iis_ssi.dll
>   LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\static.dll
>   LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll
>   LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\urlauthz.dll
>   LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authbas.dll
>   LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll
>   LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
>   LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wkscli.dll
>   LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll
>   LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authmd5.dll
>   LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authmap.dll
>   LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iprestr.dll
>   LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\diprestr.dll
>   LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\modrqflt.dll
>   LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\logcust.dll
>   LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\custerr.dll
>   LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\loghttp.dll
>   LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisetw.dll
>   LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisfreb.dll
>   LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisreqs.dll
>   LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\isapi.dll
>   LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\filter.dll
>   LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cgi.dll
>   LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisfcgi.dll
>   LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\validcfg.dll
>   LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll
>   LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
>   LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll
>   LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll
>   LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll
>   LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
>   LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
>   LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
>   LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll
>   LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\wbhst_pm.dll
>   LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine.dll
>   LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\60c56b4f785f2f9bead35377666101fa\mscorlib.ni.dll LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\54033b57c6e312b97e03fdfaa774de8a\System.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Core\3724522762ba46884f8af189cfc3fc88\System.Core.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web\4278a8648a7ac23e94ed371a54d7cf25\System.Web.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
>   LoadedModule[103]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.8dc504e4#\cd998bf0feef6e9fc953d8da28f9a608\System.Web.ApplicationServices.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Configuration\552d85acc55c3d44f82e41c79a8794a5\System.Configuration.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml\77e517ff63541574fc9ec0c9d747672c\System.Xml.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[106]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
>   LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll
>   LoadedModule[108]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
>   LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runt19c51595#\e3f1d8ad7df73ec8256c56b7091f470d\System.Runtime.Caching.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.B83e9cb53#\d3325e0467897ce1f0f32b47b0216300\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[111]=C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
>   LoadedModule[112]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.JScript\5d71c3ae2491b3ef4e54a444a2279c0d\Microsoft.JScript.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.28b9ef5a#\ca90f378b97efaa37da4d017c97bd98a\System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Drawing\c5ef7c3cdcdb2a6de17d19bbed30b0a3\System.Drawing.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.Mobile\6c4a7daf20c202926423c4e37dc88159\System.Web.Mobile.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.82d5542b#\1bc4f3cbdde7cf0da20e28de3fd5fc04\System.Web.RegularExpressions.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.Services\7f6bc0339c2089f81ddcbaefd6ded8d4\System.Web.Services.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[118]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data\9d45d71eae9d1245741b0f2b171a738e\System.Data.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[119]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
>   LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Net.Http\c1b254bd1b7d3acefb613ed942de5b48\System.Net.Http.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[121]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Security\6672f1331114307a79fea1e537f36a58\System.Security.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[122]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Transactions\e247ba7dcdd11024b5032c5e8e9958ea\System.Transactions.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[123]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
>   LoadedModule[124]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Numerics\437cf967c9ead3d91405323a8e499a1f\System.Numerics.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[125]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data86569bbf#\9d7ce9227e4c7b66f86a1db163eb38a0\System.Data.OracleClient.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[126]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll
>   LoadedModule[127]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.CSharp\dc5ed15e3cd54a03c0cc77fd2a2ab87d\Microsoft.CSharp.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[128]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Ente96d83b35#\97344f5c3d81cab274b28df4dd6c6718\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[129]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.IdentityModel\d01b299d1342b66df5c599bf5e8147ec\System.IdentityModel.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[130]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runteb92aa12#\634ae69317e449509a4cc0aea99619fd\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll LoadedModule[131]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.ServiceModel\a31d8078434c0053a8653aadfa459907\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[132]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Serv14b62006#\2c5dd64d92dc2af5eefc6d8df55f13b1\System.ServiceModel.Activation.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[133]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Servf73e6522#\af68656a47b83bf104220eb49452b36f\System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[134]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Activities\b4ed839a23f4b02b7f09a771ce33ba9c\System.Activities.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[135]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Serv14259fd9#\eab902a608f4267dee1a2234ba4eda38\System.ServiceModel.Activities.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[136]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Workd8194f73#\e5a9066add9eae70450ee3c7331301d2\System.WorkflowServices.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[137]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data7706cdc8#\e513a683aaa92b5f37acc648232292b7\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[138]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml.Linq\8380738635c5d623d74298a649559660\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[139]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Comp46f2b404#\51e67d223bf1a719479131cb9aeca8b6\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[140]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.2486c0f5#\672f03f9b3cf1fda55a50304eac476b6\System.Web.DynamicData.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[141]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Ente96d83b35#\97344f5c3d81cab274b28df4dd6c6718\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
>   LoadedModule[142]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
>   LoadedModule[143]=C:\Windows\system32\security.dll
>   LoadedModule[144]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SECUR32.DLL
>   LoadedModule[145]=C:\Windows\system32\schannel.DLL
>   LoadedModule[146]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
>   LoadedModule[147]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
>   LoadedModule[148]=C:\Windows\system32\ncryptsslp.dll
>   FriendlyEventName=Stopped working ConsentKey=APPCRASH AppName=IIS
>   Worker Process AppPath=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   NsPartner=windows NsGroup=windows8"

Comment: May be try a repair installation of the .net framework or uninstall/reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll get to it, i want to understand the error before as this is my prod env. do u know a way i can increase the event viewer lgf level ?

Comment: If it is only on your prod machine, you should check if it happens also on a test machine. Last Time I saw this error it was a damaged .net installtion.

Comment: thanks i did, it does not reproduce in my dev environment. any other ideas ?